# X-CUBE-BLE1 Applications Compilation Issues with MDK-ARM

Tags: stm32

I am trying to compile X-Cube-Ble1 SensorDemo Application using MDK-ARM.

The path of the project is

> STM32CubeExpansion_BLE1_V2.5.1\Projects\Multi\Applications\SensorDemo\MDK-ARM\STM32L053R8-Nucleo

but I am getting following compilation errors even though the files are present in the respective directories. I have not made any changes to the applications.
I just unzipped the X-Cube-Ble1 and tried to compile the applications provided in the zip.

```
Using Compiler 'V5.05 update 2 (build 169)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'SensDemo_L053R8_NUCLEO'
assembling startup_stm32l053xx.s...
compiling main.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\main.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_interface.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\bluenrg_interface.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling clock.c...
..\..\Src\clock.c(39): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "clock.h": No such file or directory
  #include "clock.h"
..\..\Src\clock.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling sensor_service.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\sensor_service.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling cube_hal_l0.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\cube_hal_l0.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32xx_it.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\stm32xx_it.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_nucleo.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\BSP\STM32L0xx_Nucleo\stm32l0xx_nucleo.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32_bluenrg_ble.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\BSP\X-NUCLEO-IDB04A1\stm32_bluenrg_ble.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling system_stm32l0xx.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\Src\system_stm32l0xx.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_adc.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_adc.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_adc_ex.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_adc_ex.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_adc_ex.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_cortex.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_cortex.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_cortex.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_dma.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_dma.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_flash.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_flash.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_flash.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_flash_ex.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_flash_ex.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_flash_ex.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_gpio.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_gpio.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_pwr.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_pwr.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_rcc.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_rcc.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling stm32l0xx_hal_spi.c...
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L0xx\Include\stm32l0xx.h(148): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "stm32l053xx.h": No such file or directory
    #include "stm32l053xx.h"
..\..\..\..\..\..\Drivers\STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32l0xx_hal_spi.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling hci.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\hci.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\hci.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_gap_aci.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_gap_aci.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_gap_aci.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_gatt_aci.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_gatt_aci.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_gatt_aci.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_hal_aci.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_hal_aci.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_hal_aci.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_l2cap_aci.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_l2cap_aci.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_l2cap_aci.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_utils_small.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_utils_small.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\hci\controller\bluenrg_utils_small.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling bluenrg_itf_template.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\Interface\bluenrg_itf_template.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\Interface\bluenrg_itf_template.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling gp_timer.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\gp_timer.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\gp_timer.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling list.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\list.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\list.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
compiling osal.c...
"no source": Error:  #5: cannot open source input file "..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\osal.c": No such file or directory
..\..\..\..\..\..\Middlewares\ST\STM32_BlueNRG\SimpleBlueNRG_HCI\utils\osal.c: 0 warnings, 1 error
"STM32L053R8_NUCLEO\SensorDemoProject.axf" - 16 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:03
```